# How do I create an AWS RDS Database in Europe

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

If I can create a database in Europe, I have a lot less to worry about with reagards to data protection. [amazon's docs](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/globalinfrastructure/regional-product-services/) imply that I can create one in Ireland.  When I get to the apropriate stage of the wizard though, I only get `us-east-1a`, `us-east-1b` and `us-east-1c`:

[image: aws availability zones]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Is there somewhere else I can select a more general region?

Answer (score 2):

I've just discovered you can select the region from a drop down at the top right of the screen.  (I spent ages looking for this before asking here, then moments later I saw it).  Hope this helps someone else.

[image: region]